# Do I need multiple GPUs to use nVidia Surround?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, graphics-card

I'm not at all familiar with nVidia surround. I have a 560GTX and two 1920x1080 monitors side by side and was curious if I can play Skyrim on both monitors like a partial surround using this one card, or do I have to have two cards and 3 monitors to do any type of surround display?

Comment: This depends on your graphics card, but most newer ones can do Surround with three on a single card.  Note that there's a reason you usually see three, not two - putting the monitor bezels right in the center of the play area is HUGELY annoying.

Comment: I have a 560gtx. I technically have a third monitor but its really a TV sitting a few feet to the side for watching movies. So I may be able to trick it to where it keeps the center on my middle display. I just wanted to make my right display useful for full screen play.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.immersaview.com/resources/nvidia-surround-set-up

No, you can't, you'd need two cards

> NVIDIA Surround can only be enabled on a GeForce GTX series graphics card. With newer GTX 600 series cards you can set-up NVIDIA Surround on a single card with no additional requirements. Using surround with older cards (GTX 260 and up, 460 and up, 560 and up) requires at least 2 cards in SLI mode in conjunction with an SLI-capable motherboard.

As well as that you'd need a third monitor

> Note: Surround only supports 3 projectors in horizontal span mode. Other display layouts are supported using NVIDIA’s Mosaic technology on Quadro cards.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. That said you should still be able to run the two monitors through one card.